# Enable HTTPS on thingsboard

Tags: ssl, https, certbot, thingsboard

Im trying to enable HTTPS using this guide (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/pe/add-haproxy-ubuntu/#step-10-refresh-haproxy-configuration) but i got stuck on step 9 i believe.

```
sudo certbot-certonly --domain your_domain --email your_email
```

I get the following error

```
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --tls-sni-01-port 8443
```

As far as i can tell, lets encrypt no longer supports this argument (tls-sni-01-port) or using ports other than 80 and 443. I got this from (https://serverfault.com/questions/805666/certbot-letsencrypt-on-different-port-than-443).

I am uncertain as how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my docker-compose.yml for Thingsboard + HTTPS through Nginx reverse proxy with automatic Let's Encrypt certificates: https://github.com/michalfapso/thingsboard_docker_https/

It uses [linuxserver/swag](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag) which takes care of the certificates and is kept in sync with Let's Encrypt requirements by the [linuxserver.io](https://www.linuxserver.io/) community.